# @Html.CheckBoxFor issue in razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that respond to a submit button.

I have my one checkbox as following:

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBoxValue)
```

How can I get if checked YES otherwise NO preferably as string in my model ..

```
  public bool CheckBoxValue { get; set; } OR
  public string CheckBoxValue { get; set; }
```

Please help.

Thanks

**Update**

This was the way to go.

```
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBoxValue)

   public bool CheckBoxValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: You should not need that.  Why do you want a string pretending to be a boolean?

Comment: You are right however I need it as a string rather than a bool :(

Comment: You shouldn't need that in your **view** model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking for a user-friendly display of the value?  That should happen in the view, not in the model.  Something like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBoxValue)
<!-- some other markup, blah blah blah -->
@(Model.CheckBoxValue ? "Yes" : "No")
```

As much as possible, the model should contain only the structure and logical functionality of the data.  Any user-friendliness or anything that users see and interact with should go in the view.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, you *could* add something like this to the model:

```
public string CheckBoxDisplayValue
{
    get
    {
        return CheckBoxValue ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```

Note: This is *in addition to* the `bool` property `CheckBoxValue` which is what gets bound to the view, not in place of it.  The model needs a boolean, so `CheckBoxValue` is that boolean.  All this does is add a read-only property to the model to show a user-friendly display for the boolean value.

But this is not recommended.  It sounds like you have an end goal that you're not specifying in the question here, and there's probably a better way to achieve that end goal.

Comment: David, I want to pass YES if the checkbox is checked to a property in my model . and NO if it is left unchecked.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper: Why?  To echo SLaks' comment above, why does the model need a string pretending to be a boolean?  You could add a property to the Model similar to what you tried (I'll add it to my answer), but that's not really placing the concerns where they need to be.

Comment: For example a person is trying to fill aform there and is a checkbox that they select if they want to receive the news letter and leave it unchecked if they don't. This information is then sent via an email to the administrator. Now I have a an HTTPpost in my home controller that responds to action result (contactInfoViewModel form) and once the form contact message is validated.. info is sent to admin.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper: That doesn't mean the string belongs in the model.  The model should carry the boolean data, that's all.  If a string needs to be shown to the user, it goes in the view.  If it needs to be sent to a service, it goes in the service call.  Neither of which are part of the model.

Comment: In that case this should work right? `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBoxValue)` in view and `public bool CheckBoxValue { get; set; }` in the model.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper: That should get you a boolean model property and a checkbox in the view bound to that property, yes.